# SQL content 'ño' being translated to chinese character in HTML

Tags: html, sql

I'm putting the output of an sql query into HTML and the special characters are being translated to chinese characters.

For example, my sql content is 'Ficha de Datos - Español'. When I run my query and put this content in HTML, I get this output: 'Ficha de Datos - Espa駉l'.

I've used HTML lang set to es but this doesn't help. 
Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: you need to use the SAME charset throughout your ENTIRE pipeline: html, php, php->database connection, database tables/fields, database->php replies, html output, blah blah blah. Any mismatches anywhere will cause your text to get trashed.

Comment: Try adding the meta '<meta charset="utf-8">' in your document '<header>' - for unicode support (RTL languages)

Comment: Both answers thank you! Using cpanel, it interpreted the file as gb2312 and when I saved a change my meta charset was that. Changing this back to utf-8 fixed the issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing meta charset to utf-8 to match all other documents resolved this issue.

from:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
```

to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```